# Roll a pair of dice

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

(a) What is the probability of rolling at least 9?

I draw the table and I came up with and answer of 5/18 from adding P(9)+P(10)+P(11)+P(12)

(b) if one die rolls a 4, What is the probability of rolling at least 9?

From the table I see that P(9|4) = 2/8, P(10|4) = 2/9, for 11 and 12 the probability is zero.
Hence my answer to (b) is the sum of the two above probabilities which equals 17/36.

Are any of this answers correct or wrong?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Your first answer looks correct.  Your second answer looks wrong (you need something more complicated than simple addition if you are going to use conditional probability), though it may depend on what "one die rolls a 4" means. Does "one" mean a particular die, or at least one of the two dice, or exactly one of the two?

Comment: I think both are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why you have $P(9|4)=\frac29$ but $P(10|4)=\frac2{8}$.   I think they have to be the same, perhaps $\frac16$, $\frac2{11}$ or $\frac2{10}$.

Since RowanS disagree with me on the second question, here is my table of each die and their sum, with each pairing equally probable.

```
    Red 1   2   3   4   5   6
Blue                            
1       2   3   4   5   6   7
2       3   4   5   6   7   8
3       4   5   6   7   8   9
4       5   6   7   8   9   10
5       6   7   8   9   10  11
6       7   8   9   10  11  12
```

- if the red die rolls a $4$, the probability of the sum being  at least $9$ is (looking at the column) $\dfrac{2}{6}=\dfrac13$
- if either die rolls a $4$, the probability of the sum being  at least $9$ is (looking at the column and row) $\dfrac{4}{11}$
- if exactly one rolls a $4$, the probability of the sum being  at least $9$ is (looking at the column and row but not where they intersect) $\dfrac{4}{10}=\dfrac25$

Comment: if either rolls a 4 is what I came up with just above your answer and they agree. :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Answer for both the parts are given as below

[image]

Comment: EDIT:
for part (b)
P(sum = 9|given one die rolls a 4) = 2/11
P(sum = 10|give one die rolls a 4) = 2/11
The sum = 4/11, I think this answer looks correct.

Comment: I made a mistake, I shoud divide by P(4)